# One-To-Many Relationships Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, entity-relationship

After three days trying  to do that alone and after reading a lot of topics, impossible to configure one-to-many relationships in core data.

In my app, i save all the new user information in an entity called Users by this code :

```
 Users *dataUsers = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Users" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];

    [dataUsers setUsername:usernameRegistration.text.capitalizedString];
    [dataUsers setPassword:passwordRegistration1.text];
    [dataUsers setEmailAddress:mail1.text];
    [dataUsers setRightOrLeft:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:rightOrLeftHanded.selectedSegmentIndex ]];



    NSError *error = nil;
    if(![_managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        //handle the error
    }
```

Now i call all these information in a different view controller to perform the recognition username - password and access to the next page.

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
_managedObjectContext=[appDelegate managedObjectContext];    

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
NSEntityDescription *usersDescription= [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Users" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:usersDescription];


NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"username" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];



NSError  *error = nil;
NSMutableArray *mutableFetchresults = [[_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]mutableCopy];
if(mutableFetchresults == nil) {
    //handle error
}
[self setUsersData:mutableFetchresults];
// different steps for the recognition
```

Ok it works each user can log in and access to the next page.

Now , in this next page the user has to create a new session. So i created a new entity called Sessions. Each user can have several sessions but each session is linked with only one user.

```
 Sessions *session = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Sessions" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
NSNumber *howManySwingsSessionSaved = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:howManySwingsSession];
[session setName:_sessionNameTextField.text];
[session setHowManySwings:howManySwingsSessionSaved];
[session setClub:choosenClub];
NSDate *dateSaved = [NSDate date];
[session setDate:dateSaved];


NSError *error = nil;
if(![_managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    //handle the error
}
```

Each session is successfully saved.
So my question is : how can i link the new session created with the current user connected into my app ?
I want to get the current user and add him this new session.
Actually my code save each user and each session separately.

All help will be very appreciated :)

Thanks guys !!

EDIT :
I have already created the relationship in the xcdmodel

Comment: For storing usernames and passwords, it's generally preferable to do so using the Keychain, through the NSURLCredentialStorage API.

Comment: Yep i know but my app will be only a proof of concept so it doesn't matter.  i will never post my app on the apple store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed !!!! 
There is probably better solution but this one works, i hope it could be helpful for other guys in the future

In the .m where the user create a new session

```
Sessions *session = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Sessions"     inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
NSNumber *howManySwingsSessionSaved = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:howManySwingsSession];
[session setName:_sessionNameTextField.text];
[session setHowManySwings:howManySwingsSessionSaved];
[session setClub:choosenClub];
NSDate *dateSaved = [NSDate date];
[session setDate:dateSaved];
```

// I insert a new session in Sessions

```
for (int i = 0; i< [usersData count]; i++)
{ Users* users = (Users *) [usersData objectAtIndex:i];
if ([users.username isEqualToString: @"your_username"])
{
    Users * currentUser = [usersData objectAtIndex:i];
    [currentUser addSessionObject:session];
}

}
```

// i compare each username of my usersData with the username i want , i define it as the currentUser and finally i add the session created to it.

```
NSError *error = nil;
if(![_managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    //handle the error
}
```

// i save the all

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get the current user and add him this new session. Actually
>   my code save each user and each session separately.

You haven't shown us the model, but it looks like you need to add relationships to your entities. Your `Session` entity needs a to-one relationship to `User`, and the inverse relationship should be a to-many relationship from `User` to `Session`. Once you have that, select the entities in your model and use the Editor->Create NSManagedObject Subclass...` command to generate subclasses for each entity. If you look at the resulting header files, you'll find some accessors that you can use to create the relationships between objects. You may not even need to use them -- for example, you could do something like:

```
Sessions *session = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Sessions" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
session.user = theCurrentUser;
```

Comment: Great. So what's preventing you from setting the relationships you want as described above?

Comment: Yep sorry i edited some minutes before your post, i have already created my session.h and .m and the same thing for user. Okay for the currentUser but how i can get get this currentUser ? I mean how i can say this session is linked with the user having the username @"toto" for example ?